# I disconnected nest thermostat to move to another location. Reconnected it. Now getting no power to Rh wire. Tested it and reading 30 volts.Any ideas?

Tags: electrical

Disconnected nest thermostat to move to new location. Reconnected and getting E4 code. Tested and reading 30 volts. Any ideas.

Comment: Can you post info about your HVAC system? Does "move to new location" mean that you simply spliced some more thermostat cable in to move the thermostat within your house, or that you moved it to a new house?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick answer as I cannot physically see what you have. In typical thermostats power is normally the R and C wires. C is the common connected to the transformer and is common to relays etc. R is the other side of the transformar and gives you normally about 24VAC between R and C. You should have about 24 volts AC between them, if not you probably have a broken wire. The error: "E4, E24 and E74 No power to Rh wire detected." Tells us that it is not detecting power. The hookup chart shows R gets connected to Rh. Hopefully this gets you going.